# opencart 1.5.6.4 disable page cache for module

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, caching, opencart

How to disable the Cache for part of page? There is a block that is updated dynamically, but I can't seem to disable its caching... module with feedbacks and when ceche is enable feedbacks stop showing on random ... 
Perhaps I'm missing something in full page caching mechanics?
Please help.

controller :

```
$this->load->model('catalog/review');
    $current_store = $this->config->get('config_store_id');


    $feedbacks = $this->model_catalog_review->getFeedbacksByStore($current_store);


    $this->data['feedbackscrazys'][] = array(
        'feedback_name'  => $feedbacks['form_name'],
        'feedback_text'  => $feedbacks['feedback']
    );

    $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
```

model:

```
 public function getFeedbacksByStore($id) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "feedbackcrazy";
    $sql .= " WHERE shop_id = ".$id." AND show_index=1";
    $sql .= " ORDER BY shop_id  asc";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->row;
}
```

and the index.php

```
<div class="col-md-53 col-sm-55 col-xs-55 all-paddtop18">
            <div class="contentItem">
                <div id="footerfeedback" class="group">
                    <div id="footerfeedbackContentBox">
                        <div id="footerfeedbackTitle">
                            <span id="footerfeedbackYourWord">YOUR</span>
                            <span id="footerfeedbackOpinionsWord">FEEDBACK</span>
                        </div>
                        <div id="footerfeedbackContent" class="group">
                            <div id="footerfeedbackItem">
                                <div id="footerfeedbackItemContent">
                                    ...
                                </div>
                                <div id="footerfeedbackItemDivider">-</div>
                                <div id="footerfeedbackItemCustomer">...</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="footerfeedbackShareButton">
                        <a href="feedback">Share your opinion</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var feedbacks = function() {

    for ( var i = 0; i < complex.length; i++ ) {
        var name = complex[i]['feedback_name'];
        var desc = complex[i]['feedback_text'];
    }

var i = 0;
var fnchange = function() {

    $('#footerfeedbackItemContent').animate({'opacity': 0}, 2000, function () {
        $(this).text(desc);
    }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 2500);

    $('#footerfeedbackItemCustomer').animate({'opacity': 0}, 2000, function () {
        $(this).text(name);
    }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 2500);

    if( ++i < json.length ){
        setTimeout(fnchange, 10000);
    } else {
        i = 0;
        setTimeout(fnchange, 10000);
    }
};
setTimeout(fnchange, 1);
};
setTimeout(feedbacks,1);
```

});